# Drop down selection resets the value of previously selected drop down in angular

Tags: angular

I have a form in angular which has multiple drop down in it.

Drop Down 1-->

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Title" 
    formControlName="Title">
    <mat-option>Title</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Mr">Mr</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Miss">Miss</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Drop Down 2 -->

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Country" 
    formControlName="Country">
    <mat-option>Country</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="US">US</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="UK">UK</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem is when I select the value for Country from the drop down , the previously selected value for Title drop down is reset only on UI.

PS: When I fetch the value for the Title drop down while saving, I get the value which was previously selected.

Comment: Please bind Title and Country to different variables, so change [(value)]="selected"[(value)]="selected_title" and [(value)]="selected_country" in both select.

Comment: Worked . Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, you used the same [(value)] in value, so it behaves the same way. Just change one or both.

Answer (score 0):

You are double binding same 'selected' variable in both the values for select option.
When one is changed, the value in other option is changed as well as both are double-binded to 'selected' variable.
Change one of them to some other variable.